# How to override defined values in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor

I want to override the `#define iAds @"@xyz"`.

Answer (score 4):

It is the same as to override #define in c. In general, you should use this construction:

```
#ifdef iAds
    // Already defined - undefine
    #undef iAds
#endif
#define iAds @"@xyz"
```

But it will work only if your header compiles after the header where original iAds macro defined.